# Delphi: Passing a parameter to a running service to act on

Tags: delphi, service

We have a service (written in C#) running to check somethings every 10 minutes and if something new happened, then send an email to someone special.

We also have other Delphi program and want to pass a parameter to the service to act on and send email immediately (I mean regardless than 10 minutes interval).

How to do that while service is running ?

**note:** There is no way to migrate to C# we have to do that in Delphi.

Comment: -the right way sending windows message using API
or using file to write the parameters from delphi app and read from C# app
or using windows clipboard if service only running under server "not user pc"

Comment: @KarimEzzat So my question is about how to write the parameters from delphi app!!

Comment: @Omid i've voted up to compensate for that. It's a valid question, and you've provided enough information to come up with an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's also a possibility to use [`ControlService`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682108%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API to send the service a user-defined control code. (The service has to be written to respond to that specific control code.)

Comment: That allows you to send a single value in the range 128-255. Which may suffice, so long as the sender does not wish to communicate very much information.

Comment: It may suffice if the intention is simply "do something now, regardless of the interval", as it seems to be in this case.

Comment: Yes, it's a fine way to do that

Comment: This is fine if you need a trigger, and you don't have further plans for the software. If you need to run the two processes on different machines, it becomes hairy quickly. You'll have to mess with firewalls between the machines, and you'll need special permissions. That's not very smooth to deploy. Additionally, you're building in a hard dependency to Windows API's. The programmer in me says: "meh, it works"; the architect says: "keep the bigger picture of the system in mind"

Comment: @WoutervanNifterick Overengineering, on the other hand, gets you pretty hairy results, too. ;-)

Comment: @TOndrej: heh, true dat yo. You did receive my up-vote; I just wanted to make a side note here. :)

Answer (score 4):

You need to use some form of inter process communication (IPC). There are many possibilities. Most commonly used for such a scenario are named pipes and TCP/sockets.

Answer (score 3):

There are some good answers here already... and here's mine:
You could use a text file or the windows registry to flag for action. This way your Delphi service can react upon start-up should the trigger have occured while your service was not running. Any information/parameters you wish to convey can be included in the registry-key value or as file data.

**Win Registry Method:**
If you use a registry-key make sure that both apps can read and write to the same key. 
In your Delphi Service implement the `RegNotifyChangeKeyValue` WinAPI which will notify when the key is added/altered. Here's an idea how you can implement the listner in Delphi: [Monitoring Registry Changes](http://delphi.about.com/od/kbwinshell/l/aa052003a.htm)

**File Method:**
To be notified about file changes you do not need to poll for changes. Below is code for a solution based on the `FindFirstChangeNotification` WinAPI. Your Delphi Service can implement the TFileWatch class. You will also need a unit with the class [TDirectoryWatch class](http://www.angusj.com/delphi/dirwatch.html) by Angus Johnson.

```
unit FileWatch;

interface

uses Classes,
     SysUtils,
     DirWatch; //by Angus Johnson: http://www.angusj.com/delphi/dirwatch.html

type TFileNotifyEventType = (feCreated, feModified, feDeleted);
     TFileNotifyEvent = procedure(Sender: TObject; FileEventType : TFileNotifyEventType) of object;

     TFileWatch = class(TComponent)
     private
       FDirWatch : TDirectoryWatch;
       FFileToWatch : string;
       FFileAge : integer;           //if -1 then file does not exist
       FFileExists : boolean;
       procedure OnFolderChangeEvent(Sender: TObject);
     protected

     public
        OnFileNotifyEvent : TFileNotifyEvent;
        property Filename : string read FFileToWatch;
        constructor Create(aOwner: TComponent; FileToWatch : string);
        destructor Destroy();
     end;
implementation

{ TFileWatch }

constructor TFileWatch.Create(aOwner: TComponent; FileToWatch: string);
begin
  inherited Create(aOwner);

  FDirWatch := TDirectoryWatch.Create(Self);
  FDirWatch.Directory := ExtractFilePath(FileToWatch);
  FDirWatch.OnChange := OnFolderChangeEvent;
  FDirWatch.NotifyFilters := [nfFilename, nfLastWrite];
  FDirWatch.Active := true;

  FFileToWatch := FileToWatch;
  FFileAge := FileAge(FFileToWatch);
  FFileExists := FFileAge > -1;
end;

destructor TFileWatch.Destroy;
begin
  FDirWatch.Free;
  inherited Destroy;
end;

procedure TFileWatch.OnFolderChangeEvent(Sender: TObject);
var MyFileAge : integer;
    MyFileExists : boolean;

    FileEventType : TFileNotifyEventType;
begin
  //Check to see if the event has been fired by our file in question
  MyFileAge := FileAge(FFileToWatch);
  if MyFileAge = FFileAge then
    exit;  //Nothing has happened, exit.

  //Figure out if the file has been created, modified or deleted
  MyFileExists := MyFileAge > -1;
  if MyFileExists and not FFileExists then
    FileEventType := feCreated
  else if not MyFileExists and FFileExists then
    FileEventType := feDeleted
  else
    FileEventType := feModified;

  FFileAge := MyFileAge;
  FFileExists := MyFileExists;

  if Assigned(OnFileNotifyEvent) then
    OnFileNotifyEvent(Self, FileEventType);
end;

end.
```

Comment: That seems the simplest way to do such action. I should give it a try.

Comment: @Omid Why would you choose these options. They are flaky. The registry is a very dubious IPC mechanism. Waiting for file modifications is also pretty weak.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I see. I haven't accepted this yet. I think TOndrej's solution is more regular.

Comment: @Omid That's true unless you need to send information. In which case it is no good.

Answer (score 1):

I often communicate via a database. I'd store a certain value with process X, and process Y reads it.

The nice thing about that design is that the two applications don't need to know eachother. They can easily run on different machines, and you can have multiple readers and writers, so you can easily scale things up. You also get encryption and compressed connections for free if you need it, and all sorts of complicated multi user stuff is taken care of.

Comment: How does the reader get notified that there are changes? Do DBs have standard ways to notify readers?

Comment: @davidheffernan: It doesn't. Instead, you poll the database. Either with a timer or on demand. Omid tells us that information gets updated every 10 minutes, so it's probably enough to poll the database every minute or 10 seconds or so. Especially if it needs to send an email, i don't think the extra speed of direct IPC would justify the maintenance downsides.  But, my suggestion to use a db is only useful if you already have a db in the project. For a single trigger it would be overkill of course.

Comment: Via a DB you can run processes on different physical machines, and you don't have any platform dependencies like you do if you communicate via some Windows API. You can easily replace the e-mailer with a Python script on Linux, without having to modify the other module.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest adding a WCF Service to (hosted by) your Windows service exposing the required function.